# Using a PowerShell script, is there a way to get a list of Items from a folder that excludes items that have a duplicate BaseName?

Tags: powershell, filter, duplicates, get-childitem

I want to store items in a var from a directory with duplicate names, but different extensions. For example: there are files with `.jpg` and files with `.webp` with the same BaseName. I would like to excludes those and only add the ones that don't have a similar `.webp` twin.

Code I used to get all the files:

```
$images = Get-ChildItem $dir
```

I would like to store all the files that don't have a `.webp` twin with the same BaseName in `$images`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet:

```
$images = Get-ChildItem -File $dir\*.jpg, $dir\*.webp |
            Group-Object BaseName |
              Where-Object { $_.Group.Extension -notcontains '.webp' } |
                ForEach-Object Group
```

<sup>Note: If *recursive* file retrieval were to be used (`-Recurse`), you could simplify to

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File $dir -Include *.jpg, *.webp`; perhaps surprisingly, `-Include` is only properly supported *with* `-Recurse` - see [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304).</sup>